# Unzip Seleted files using winzip SSIS

Tags: ssis, unzip

I am able to unzip all files using below command in SSIS processTask.

Executable: c:\Program Files\PKWARE\PKZIPC\pkzipc.exe

Arguments: -extract -overwrite  "C:\MyFolder\xyz.tar.gz" "c:\MyFolder\"

there are multiple file in the zip folder and unzipping process is extracting files in alphabetical(a-z) order but I want to unzip selected files on custom order.

Comment: On top of head, you can use `File system task` to move files in folders and extract as required.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more!